# css with slideshow and pager block and absolute positioning

Tags: css

I have a css problem with my drupal site (www.terrafirmasouth.co.uk) to do with the slideshow caption box and the pager block underneath.

When you access my site for the first time, the transparent caption box (bottom left) on the slideshow starts lower by the height of the pager block below then adjusts itself to the correct position. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> also recreates the problem.

If I disable the pager block the problem goes away.

By adding `position:absolute` to the pager block the jumping stops, but the text below my pager block seems to interfere (overlap?) with my pager block, and I cant click on the numbers anymore to change slide .

I want to be able to show the pagers (1-6) under the slide, so that they can be clicked (I have already tested this with no `position:absolute` and it works fine, but I have the jumping problem of course).

I have attached my latest css below, but this has not gone live onto my site yet, just running it on my pc using xammp.

```
/* my caption box */
.trcaption {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 10px;
    background: #353535;
    opacity: 0.85;
    filter:alpha(opacity=85);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
/* title inside caption box */
#trtitle {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'LatoLight', Arial, sans-serif;
}
/* read more link inside caption box */

#trlink a {
    color: #008C07;
    float: left;
    font-size : 12px;
}
/* pager block under my slideshow  */

.views-slideshow-controls-bottom {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
}
/* pager item i.e. number number */

.views-slideshow-pager-field-item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
/* show active pager with grey background */

.views-slideshow-pager-field-item.active {
    background: #E8E8E8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding something absolute, make sure nothing else with property absolute is clashing with same, you can use `z-index` to arrange them in layer.

that will stop the clashing and things should work fine then. :)

For more help please add some working code, apart from CSS or create fiddel on jsfiddle

Comment: @Barnee many thanks, taht has fixed the problem. I added z-index:1 to my pager block and I can now click on the pager numbers. However, I cant seem to add a margin at the bottom . 'code' 
.views-slideshow-controls-bottom {

 position: absolute;
 text-align:center;
 width: 100%;
 z-index:1;


} 'code'

Comment: try this `.views-slideshow-controls-bottom { position: absolute; text-align:center; width: 100%; z-index:1; margin-bottom:10px; }`  the code was not having any thing for margin :)

Comment: with position absolute , i cant put a margin in, when I comment out position absolute, the margin appears?

Comment: For this I will require HTML code otherwise this will be playing in clouds, and may give wrong answer :)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I couldn't seem to apply a margin-bottom on my pagers block so I added one to its parent element which did the trick (I used padding-bottom ). I have it all working now, no jumping about. Strange thing though, in IE the margin between my pager block (under my slideshow) and the text underneath is hardly anything, but on firefox and chrome is just right. there must be subtle differences between the IE and rest of world when it comes to padding. thanks for all your help.